# Javascript: Compare two selected files by file path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, blob

I'm looking for a way to check if two files/documents (PDF, JPG, PNG) are the same.

If a user selects one or more files, I convert the File Object to a javascript object. I'm keeping the size, type, filename and I create a blob so I can store the object in my redux store.

When a user selects another file I want to compare this file with the files that already has been added (so I can set the same blobURL).

I can check if two files has the same name, type and size but there is a change that all these properties match and the files aren't the same so I would like to check the file path. Unfortunately, that property isn't provided in the File Object. Is there a way to get this or another solution to make sure both files are (not) the same?

Comment: JavaScript deliberately hides this information for security reasons.

Comment: @Barmar Good to know. Thanks. Do you know another solution to compare the files?

Comment: No, that's my point, you're not supposed to be able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to get the real path, but that doesn't matter.
All you have access to is a FakePath, in the form `C:\fakepath\yourfilename.ext` (from input.value), and sometimes a bit more if you gained access to a directory.
But anyway you probably don't want to check that two files came from the same place on the hard-disk, this has no importance whatsoever, since they could very well have been modified since first access.

What you can and probably want to do however, is to check if their **content** 
are the same. 
For this, you can compare their byte content:

```js
inp1.onchange = inp2.onchange = e => {
  const file1 = inp1.files[0];
  const file2 = inp2.files[0];
  if(!file1 || !file2) return;
  compare(file1, file2)
    .then(res => console.log('are same ? ', res));
};


function compare(file1, file2) {
  // they don't have the same size, they are different
  if(file1.size !== file2.size)
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  // load both as ArrayBuffers
  return Promise.all([
    readAsArrayBuffer(file1),
    readAsArrayBuffer(file2)
  ]).then(([buf1, buf2]) => {
    // create views over our ArrayBuffers
    const arr1 = new Uint8Array(buf1);
    const arr2 = new Uint8Array(buf2);
    return !arr1.some((val, i) =>
      arr2[i] !== val // search for diffs
    );
  });
}

function readAsArrayBuffer(file) {
  // we could also have used a FileReader,
  // but Response is conveniently already Promise based
  return new Response(file).arrayBuffer();
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp1">
<input type="file" id="inp2">
```

---

Now, you say that you don't have access to the original Files anymore, and that you can only store serializable data. In this case, one less performant solution is to generate a hash from your Files.
This can be done on front-end, thanks to the [SubtleCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto),
but this operation being quite slow for big files, you may want to do it systematically from server instead of doing it on front, and to only do it on front when the sizes are the same:

```js
// a fake storage object like OP has
const store = [
  { /* an utf-8 text file whose content is `hello world`*/
    name: "helloworld.txt",
    size: 11,
    hash: "b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9" // generated from server
  }
];
// the smae file as the one we fakely stored
const sameFile = new File(['hello world'], 'same-file.txt');
// a file the same size as the one we stored (needs deep check)
const sameSizeButDifferentContent = new File(['random text'], 'differentcontent.txt');


inp.onchange = e => tryToStore(inp.files[0]);

tryToStore(sameFile); // false

tryToStore(sameSizeButDifferentContent); 
// hash: "a4e082f56a58e0855a6abbf2f4ebd08895ff85ea80e634e02b210def84b557dd"


function tryToStore(file) {
  checkShouldStore(file)
    .then(result => {
      console.log('should store', file.name, result)
      if(result)
        store.push(result);
        
      // this is just for demo, in your case you would do it on the server
      if(!result.hash)
        generateHash(file).then(h => result.hash = h);
    });
}

async function checkShouldStore(file) {
  const {name, size} = file;
  const toStore = {name, size, file}; // create a wrapper object
  // first check against the sizes (fast checking)
  const sameSizes = store.filter(obj => obj.size === file.size);
  // only if some files have the same size
  if(sameSizes.length) {
    // then we generate a hash directly
    const hash = await generateHash(file);
    if(sameSizes.some(obj => obj.hash === hash)) {
      return false; // is already in our store
    }
    toStore.hash = hash; // save the hash so we don't have to generate it on server
  }
  return toStore;
}

async function generateHash(file) {
  // read as ArrayBuffer
  const buf = await new Response(file).arrayBuffer();
  // generate SHA-256 hash using crypto API
  const hash_buf = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", buf);
  // convert to Hex
  const hash_arr = [...new Uint8Array(hash_buf)]
    .map(v => v.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"));
  return hash_arr.join('');
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I implemented your code into my project but instead of File Objects I worked with Javascript objects (properties size and a blobURL) because the previous selected files are already stored in the redux store as a blob. The ouput of the Uint8Arrays are for both almost the same. Only the last element is different while the select file is completely the same. Any idea if this has something to do with converting to a blob file?

Comment: You most likely are doing something wrong. For a first, why don't you keep the File exactly? You can store it in different places, no wonder.

Comment: Storing a File in redux results in an empty object because only serialized data can be stored

Comment: Ok... so you mean previous files are already on your server and you don't have access to it anymore? (E.g because you reloaded the page). If that's the case I may have a less optimal solution that you could use, will add it as an edit in next few hours.

Comment: Not on a server but I don't have access. To be clear, it's a web app for unpaid invoices. A user can add up to ten invoices at once and for each invoice, he can add contracts, general conditions, and reminders. This happens all in separated steps so I can't keep access to the input. Therefore I store the files in a redux store until the user submits the form and I can start uploading all the documents.

To avoid uploading some documents multiple times (like general conditions) I want to compare the newest selected file(s) with the files already in my redux store.

Comment: But because it's impossible to store a File in the redux store, I convert the File Object to a Javascript object by copying the size, name, and type and by converting the file itself to a blob file.

Comment: But Files are Blob. Where is saved the Blob if not on server? How do you generate this Blob? (once again Files are Blob, so I'm pretty sure whatever you do with the Blob can be done with the File too). Anyway, I added an other solution, less performant...

Comment: I will check your solution in a moment. To create a Blob from a file I'm using `URL.createObjectURL(file)`. A blob is temporarily stored in the memory of the browser. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL]

Comment: Naaaah... That will only block your Blob from being GarbageCollected for the Document's life-time, and you won't have access to it anymore. The only way to retrieve its data would be to fetch the blobURL, but then you'd have it twice in memory. Storing it in a plain js variable would make more sense. Before checking that Files are duplicates, did you check that you were even able to send these files correctly to your server?

Comment: What do you mean with 'Before checking that Files are duplicates, did you check that you were even able to send these files correctly to your server?' 
I'm using Firebase Storage to upload the documents but I'm waiting till the user submits the form to avoid wasting upload bandwidth and have to delete files again when a user leaves the order page early.

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking you if you are sure that your workflow currently works. You are telling me that you don't have access to the Files anymore, so I wonder how you are sending it to the server. From `{name: "foo.bar", size:22, type:"text/plain"}` there is no way you can retrieve the content of the original file, and thus that you can store it on server. So you must at one point fetch the blobURL you created right? This also means that you are tied to the document's life time, and thus that you could store it in a normal js variable.

Comment: Ow yes, that's correct. I'm fetching the blob file before uploading. If all the documents are uploaded I call `blobURL.revokeObjectURL()` on every blobURL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190271/discussion-between-kaiido-and-thore).